# Convert uncommon Datetime string to type Datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a string which is a datetime, but it's not in one of the most common formats.

```
20190316-000118619
```

Is there a elegant way of converting this to type `datetime` using a the built in conversion function?

Comment: What time is that meant to represent? What attempts have you made so far?

Comment: I'm sure we can guess what the 20190316 should be. but what about the 118619 ?

Comment: I would just need the 0001 which represents the time. The following 18619 is not required.

Comment: That doesn't tell us what time it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total guess, maybe...

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(3),STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF('20190316-000118619',9,1,'T'),16,0,'.'),14,0,':'),12,0,':'),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-'));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f5d5487164c24f333cbd312a39f2eb41)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX) = '20190316-000118619';

SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
                            SUBSTRING(@s, 1, 4),--Year
                            SUBSTRING(@s, 5, 2),--Month
                            SUBSTRING(@s, 7, 2),--Day
                            SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX('-', @s) + 1, 2),--Hour
                            SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX('-', @s) + 3, 2),--Minute
                            0,--Second
                            0--Milisecond
                        );
```